# Leiningen's eclipse plugin is asking for duck streams?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on [Seesaw Window Building](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/wiki/Window-Builder).

During the step of automatically creating eclipse project file I get errors asking for duck_streams.

[lein-eclipse](https://github.com/abrenk/lein-eclipse) doesn't look like it's been updated in 2 years which means it's using the old contrib library. However in the tutorial clojure 1.3.0 is being used.

This leaves me confused as to why the tutorial example works and what I should do to run the lein-eclipse plugin?

```
$ lein plugin install lein-eclipse 1.0.0
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'lein-eclipse:lein-eclipse:jar:1.0.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Including lein-eclipse-1.0.0.jar
Created lein-eclipse-1.0.0.jar
$ lein eclipse
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/duck_streams__init.class or clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj on classpath:  (eclipse.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5441)
    [snip]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/duck_streams__init.class or clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    [snip]
```

Comment: I use lein pom command to generate pom.xml file and then import existing maven project into Eclipse workspace. Hope it suits your needs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you found this out, but `lein-eclipse` is a bit out of date, yet I think you'd be better served by installing the [Counterclockwise plugin](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/), which as of version `0.9.0`, supports Leiningen projects natively in Eclipse.  I use this plugin and Eclipse as my primary development environment, and I like this setup quite a bit.

- [Counterclockwise](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/)
- [Counterclockwise Update Site](http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite)